# Capacity and harmonic measure

Tags: real-analysis, brownian-motion, potential-theory

Suppose $D$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $n>1$ and  $E$ a subset of its boundary. We know that if $E$ has capacity zero I.e. it is a polar set , then the harmonic measure of $E$ with respect to $D$ is also zero: $\omega(x,D)(E)=0$ for all $x\in D$. Now suppose the capacity of $E$  is $<\epsilon$. Can we say that $\omega(x,D)(E)<\epsilon?$ ($\epsilon$ is a positive arbitrary number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can say that for the Martin capacity, see https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176988187

For the classical capacity there is a correction factor of the minimum 
of the potential kernel from $x$ to $D$ as explained in that reference.

All this is in dimension 3 and higher. There are some special effects in 2D.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see any comparison between the capacity of a set and its harmonic measure. I reformulate my question this way. Suppose the capacity of $E$ is less than $\epsilon$, is there a positive constant $C$ such that $\omega(x,D)(E)<C\epsilon$ for all $x\in D$?

Comment: Harmonic measure is bounded above by the hitting probability by Brownian motion.